# Return Traits from function

Tags: rust, return-value

I've take a look to rust lib: https://github.com/cyderize/rust-websocket/
In source file https://github.com/cyderize/rust-websocket/blob/master/src/client/response.rs
I seen method begin():

```
pub fn begin(self) -> Client<DataFrame, Sender<W>, Receiver<R>> {
    let (reader, writer) = self.into_inner();
    let sender = Sender::new(writer);
    let receiver = Receiver::new(reader);
    Client::new(sender, receiver)
}
```

So... I've decide to create some simple wrapper function:

```
fn get_transport(url: &str)  ->  Client<DataFrame, Sender<Write>, Receiver<Read>> {
    let url = Url::parse(url).unwrap();
    let request = Client::connect(url).unwrap();
    let response = request.send().unwrap();
    let mut ws = response.begin();

    ws
}
```

But unfortunately  I've got error result:

```
error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `websocket::ws::sender::Sender<std::io::Write>` [E0277]
src/lib.rs:36 fn get_transport(url: &str)  ->  Client<DataFrame, Sender<Write>, Receiver<Read>> {
```

Could some one please describe me why I could not return value in this way. What the difference with begin() method in the `response.rs`?
How should I return value in my case?

**UPD1:**
After @ker recommendations I've have next code:

```
fn get_transport<W: Write, R: Read, S: Sender<W>, RE: Receiver<R>>(url: &str) -> Client<DataFrame, S, RE> {

    let url = Url::parse(url).unwrap();
    let request = Client::connect(url).unwrap();
    let response = request.send().unwrap();
    let mut ws = response.begin();

    ws
}
```

But next error received in next compilation:

```
src/lib.rs:45:5: 45:7 error: mismatched types:
 expected `websocket::client::Client<websocket::dataframe::DataFrame, S, RE>`,
    found `websocket::client::Client<websocket::dataframe::DataFrame, websocket::client::sender::Sender<websocket::stream::WebSocketStream>, websocket::client::receiver::Receiver<websocket::stream::WebSocketStream>>`
(expected type parameter,
    found struct `websocket::client::sender::Sender`) [E0308]
src/lib.rs:45     ws
                  ^~
src/lib.rs:45:5: 45:7 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Seems I'v use wrong Sender and wrong Receiver :\
After corrections to use section I've have got result code:

```
fn get_transport(url: &str) -> Client<DataFrame, Sender<WebSocketStream>, Receiver<WebSocketStream>> {
    let url = Url::parse(url).unwrap();
    let request = Client::connect(url).unwrap();
    let response = request.send().unwrap();
    let mut ws = response.begin();

    ws
}
```

Unfortunately  I could not found out why I could not use generics as result value. Like this:

```
fn get_transport<R: Read, W: Write>(url: &str) -> Client<DataFrame, Sender<W>, Receiver<R>>
```

In this caseI receive error message:

```
expected `websocket::client::Client<websocket::dataframe::DataFrame, websocket::client::sender::Sender<W>, websocket::client::receiver::Receiver<R>>`,
    found `websocket::client::Client<websocket::dataframe::DataFrame, websocket::client::sender::Sender<websocket::stream::WebSocketStream>, websocket::client::receiver::Receiver<websocket::stream::WebSocketStream>>`
(expected type parameter,
    found enum `websocket::stream::WebSocketStream`) [E0308]
src/lib.rs:45     ws
                  ^~
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since any type may implment a trait, you can never know the size of an object by knowing just about the traits it implements. What you can do, is make your function generic over the types that implement Write and Read respectively. This way you can return the object, while not knowing what the actual type of the object is.

```
fn get_transport<W: Write, R: Read, S: Sender<W>, RE: Receiver<R>>(url: &str) -> Client<DataFrame, S, RE> {
    let url = Url::parse(url).unwrap();
    let request = Client::connect(url).unwrap();
    let response = request.send().unwrap();
    let mut ws = response.begin();

    ws
}
```

The reason why adding generics works, is because the generic labels point to the actual types, without knowing anything about the type except which traits they implement.

Comment: Yeah I see your point. Writer, Reader not Sized. But I do not fallow your point. How adding generics labels should help in this case?
Also I've try to add this changes to function and still have similar error. Maybe I should build sources in different fay?

Last error message (just in case):
error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `websocket::ws::sender::Sender<W>` [E0277]

Comment: So... I still not fallow how it works in response.rs case? And how to make it work in my case.

Comment: because in that case they use the `Sender` object instead of the trait.

Comment: you can find it here: https://github.com/cyderize/rust-websocket/blob/master/src/client/sender.rs

Comment: and they implement `ws::Sender` for that `Sender` type

Comment: Thank you for your help. You have bit clarify for me generics in Rust. Unfortunately I've make mistake with import Sender and Reader. Project have struct and traits with same name. 
Maybe you could point me to right text about Rust generics. Seems Rust generics much more deeper then I expect. 

Also could you please check UPD1 and comment why I receiving error in case with Traits.  As I see in rust-websocket project sources method begin() returns Traits. Not clear for me why I could not return Sender with <Write> trait.

Comment: When you use generics, the caller of the generic function decides what types to expect. Here you are forcing the type of the `W` and `R` generics. This is called specialization, and most likely not what you want. You can simply remove the generics and return the actual type `websocket::client::Client<websocket::dataframe::DataFrame, websocket::client::sender::Sender<websocket::stream::WebSocketStream>, websocket::client::receiver::Receiver<websocket::stream::WebSocketStream>>` which the error message is telling you

Answer (score 1):

You want to replace `Write` and `Send` in the return type with concrete types.

Try changing the line `let mut ws = response.begin();` to `let mut ws: () = response.begin()` and you will see an error message that will tell you what concrete types are being returned from the begin function.

Comment: I've made test as you suggest. Actually from I started from this step. Any way. In case with ws: () = ...
I receive error: `found struct `websocket::client::Client`) [E0308]`
So next step is to set this struct as return type.
<code>
fn get_transport<W: Write, R: Read>(url: &str) -> websocket::client::Client {
    let url = Url::parse(url).unwrap();
    let request = Client::connect(url).unwrap();
    let response = request.send().unwrap();
    let mut ws = response.begin();
    ws
}
</code>
Error: 
src/lib.rs:36:51: 36:76 error: wrong number of type arguments: expected 3, found 0 [E0243]